# Polyhedra with coplanar non-adjacent faces

Tags: recreational-mathematics, solid-geometry, platonic-solids

Two non-adjacent faces of a polyhedron are called $\textit{buddies}$ if they lie on the same plane. Call a polyhedron $\textit{nice}$ if every face has a buddy. What is the smallest $\textit{nice}$ polyhedron?

Any ideas?

I tried the case for a $\textit{nice}$ polygon and got the smallest polygon as the star (10 sides). This serves as a lower bound for the smallest $\textit{nice}$ polyhedron, as any cross-section of this should give a $\textit{nice}$ polygon.

Comment: "*Any* cross-section should give a nice polygon?"  If a plane cuts the polyhedron close to a vertex, it needn't intersect the polyhedron anywhere except close to the vertex, and then we'd have an ordinary convex polygon, wouldn't we?  I'm having trouble understanding the quoted sentence.  Probably I don't know what you mean by cross-section.

Comment: A non-intersecting [stella octangula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellated_octahedron) has 24 faces. But one can probably do better.

Comment: You should probably give your definition of a polyhedron, since with plenty of definitions (e.g. convex hull of finitely many points, or the intersection of finitely many half-spaces) your desired conditions are impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I make no claims to minimality, but here's a nice polycube with $20$ cubes and $72$ faces:

[image]

We start with a $2\times2\times2$ green cube, then add two diagonally opposite red cubes on each face such that the diagonals on which the red cubes lie form the edges of an inscribed regular tetrahedron on the cube.

Amusingly, it bears a strong resemblance to the MSE logo.

(Though it's a less elegant solution, one can delete two of the externally-visible green cubes from this structure to reduce the number of faces to $60$ and things still work out. Removing all green cubes disconnects the polyhedron, so we need to leave some in.)

A computer search confirmed that no polycubes with $10$ or fewer cells are nice.